# Validate ADF debug for Copy data "Move and Transform Functionality"

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I am using ADF as a pipeline for writing data from Cosmos to Kusto database by writing following activity:

1. Create temp table in Kusto database.
2. Copy data from cosmos to temp table.
3. Delete the original table, if exist in Kusto database.
4. Rename temp table to original table.

All these changes are part of JSON file from my GIT repo.

I read online that debug process in ADF does not published the changes, so I am not able to see changes in my Kusto database(temp table creation, data copy, old table deletion, renaming of temp table).

How and where to see all the changes done during Debug process of pipeline in ADF and validate(Verify that the correct table name is created and the data is dump properly in the temp table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug process runs the pipeline in the same manner as a published one and you should see the table creation, the data ingestion and the rename operation just as if you published and run it by setting a trigger or trigger manually.

However running a pipeline in a debug mode won't publish the changes to the pipeline so future triggers won't include the changes made in the debug session. To include those changes you need to publish the pipeline.

Comment: Where can I see this table creation and data ingestion activity? Is there some staging environment where all these temporary(non-publishing) task will be done?
For testing:
I created new table through activity in Pipeline and then debugged the pipeline. The Pipeline succeed and after that I checked my Kusto database for this new table and nowhere I found that newly created table

Comment: No staging environment, you should see the new table under the specified database. You are welcome to reach me and we can go over the pipeline creation and debug.